# Angular ng-repeat variable to access inside another scope objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use the variable i get from ng-repeat to accesses an object inside the scope.

My template is:

```
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">term</td>
    <td ng-repeat="block in blocks">{{ data.block.term }}</td>
    <td>{{ total.term }}</td>
</tr>
```

My scope variables are:

```
$scope.blocks = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
$scope.data = {'A': {'term': 0, 'term2': 7}, 'B': {'term': 2, 'term2': 3}, 'C': {'term': 5, 'term2': 14}};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `block` is a variable,so you cant use it as key, You need modify same as:

```
<td ng-repeat="block in blocks">{{ data[block].term }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.blocks = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  $scope.data = [{'term': 0, 'term2': 7},  {'term': 2, 'term2': 3}, {'term': 5, 'term2': 14}];
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold">term</td>
    <td ng-repeat="block in blocks track by $index">{{ data[$index].term }}</td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot user this like that because data requires index you are not providing   index block is not index in the case

You should use

```
 {{ data[block.$index].term }}
```